# Why does Picard say that Shinzon's heart is the same as his?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-nemesis

Trying to encourage a holographic Shinzon to be a bit less attack-ey:

> Look at me, Shinzon. ...Your heart, your hands, your eyes are the same as mine. The blood pumping within you, the raw material is the same. We have the same potential.

Now if Shinzon had said this, it would be plausible. He might not know that Picard has an artificial heart after a particularly vicious game of dom-jot. But Picard *does* know that, indeed Q went out of his way to *remind* Picard of it. So why does Picard say it? Is he hoping that if Shinzon assumes his place, someone will do a medical scan?

Comment: Shinzon no longer has any desire to usurp Picard as a mere duplicitous doppelganger (also, as noted by Shinzon, the Reman mines have so scarred him that it would be a largely futile effort anyway), so Picard obviously isn't talking about concerns Shinzon would "replace" him

Comment: Maybe the captain, for whatever strange reason, thought Shinzon had an artificial heart. Aside from that, Captain Picard is very much human and capable of error. Or, as the other poster opined, it could have been a metaphorical statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think Picard is being poetic (or metaphorical, if you like) in this case. "Your heart is the same as mine" doesn't just mean an organ that pumps blood; the heart is the "source" of one's feelings, one's morality, one's love et cetera. Picard is trying to appeal to Shinzon to give up his villainous schemes in favor of being a nobler man like Picard has become. It's more of a "Look at me, look what I've done, look what you could do and could be if your heart was in the right place." plea from Picard than just a direct "We're clones, so our organs are literally the same." comparison.